# Firefox exposes it's own UI elements as drag event targets - is that normal?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I was trying to figure out how to detect that a drag event is over - that user left the viewport. But in firefox, leaving viewport doesn't really cut it:

```
$(window).on("dragexit dragleave drop", dragover);
function dragOver(e) {
    console.log("over", e.target, e.relatedTarget, e.relatedTarget==null);
}
```

The `relatedTarget` should contain **to what** you dragged, while `e.target` contains **from what**. Without hesitating, firefox includes all of it's UI:

[image: image description]

It can be seen in native console too:
[image: image description]

You can't access any properties of the UI from javascript, but you can access them from Firebug, which is quite fun. Try it, but you need to use full page mode:

```js
$(window).on("dragexit dragleave drop", dragOver);
function dragOver(e) {
   console.log("over", e.target, e.relatedTarget, e.relatedTarget==null);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Some text to drag...
```

Anyway, what's that? How can I detect that the draging is over?

Comment: And if you, like me, get the idea of deleting UI with firebug, get ready for browser restart.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue; could you please tell me which version of Firefox and Firebug are you using, and under which OS? And also, if you get the same result using the Firefox's devtools instead of Firebug? Thanks!

Comment: I do even get javascript errors if I try to access any property of `e.relatedTarget` when dragging out of the viewport. I actually use `try {e.relatedTarget.tagName} catch(e) {}` to detect that user dragged something out of the viewport. You need to swing fast enough over native GUI element. Firefox 42.0, Firebug 2.0.13. It is unclear why, but native firefox console ignores these log messages.

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to see it in native console too.

Comment: I'm guessing it's intended...it has some pretty cool possibilities

Comment: @TomášZato I was able to reproduce on Firefox 42 on Mac; but it seems fixed on [Firefox Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/) – therefore will be fixed in the next Firefox's release version. Let me know if you're able to reproduce on DevEdition too.

Comment: @TomášZato forget my last comment, is still not fixed. To be precise, it seems fixed because DevEdition (and Nightly) uses [e10s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Working_with_multiprocess_Firefox), so it has two different process for content and chrome – UI. But if you disable the e10s, the issue pop up again. Not sure if it will be fixed, 'cause coming version of Firefox should be multiprocess by default, but it's worthy to file a bug.

Comment: Wow, so firefox will finally stop hanging because of, like, everything? That's some good news!

Comment: In the meantime, I filed [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1226050) if you're interested to keep an eye on this behavior – it could be also that will be resolved as WONTFIX due e10s.